# How do you configure sid name lookup over a network trust for historical sids

Tags: windows, sid, trust-relationship, name

I have the following problem with sid to name lookups.

Domain A has been migrated to Domain B with sid history.
Users in Domain B have their primary Domain B sid and a historical sid from Domain A.

I have a 2 way transitive trust between Domain B and Domain C.

There are many historical sids from domain A set in the acls in the data that is stored on a member server in domain C.

A network share is created on the member servers for users in domain B to use and store data.

This appears to be triggering a large number of a sid/name lookups to the DC located in Domain C.

When users connect to the network share on the member server in Domain C, the historical sid(from Domain A) associated with the account is also triggering a sid/name lookup.

If you check the permissions the name does not resolve

The local domain controller in domain C responds with STATUS_NONE_MAPPED.
I do not understand how to get the domain controller in Domain C to map these users.

Domain B sids translate just fine. You can see the names without a problem if you look at the acls.
historical Domain A sids fail to map.

The trust between Domain B and domain C is not quarantined.